# Different origin between GDAL/Python and ArcMap (or GIS software) of an image

Tags: python, image, geolocation, gdal, coordinate-systems

I have a Modis image and i load this image in Python using gdal library

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
INPUT_raster_1 = "C:\\Users\\samsung\\Desktop\\MODIS_LST\\LSTQC.LST_Day_1km.tif"
ds_1 = gdal.Open(INPUT_raster_1, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
geoMatrix_1 = ds_1.GetGeoTransform()
(-1770002.4756305092, 926.6254331383334, 0.0, 7444752.081661087, 0.0, -926.6254331383334)
```

with

```
top left x (x Origin) = -1770002.4756305092
top left y (y Origin) = 7444752.081661087
```

the projection is

```
ds_1.GetProjectionRef()
'PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 11N",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-117],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26911"]]'
```

when i open the same image in Arcmap 10.0 of ESRI or other GIS software and i look the layer propreties the origins are differents

[image]

with

```
 top left x (x Origin) = -1769539.16291 
 top left y (y Origin) = 7444288.76894
```

Comment: Does GDAL load it in the same coordinate system?

Comment: yes. They have the same reference system (e.g, it's the same image)

Comment: Does loading the image in arcpy give the same problem?

Comment: i did not use arcpy because i like to use open libraries during my work.

Comment: Well the difference is the same for both coordinates. and is half of the `926....` that gdal reports. Not sure what that means, but digging into some gdal docs to find out what the 926 number represents should give the answer.

Comment: 926.6254331383334 is the pixel size. But also if i do 1770002.4756305092 - 926.6254331383334 = 1769075.8501973709 the origin is different

Comment: I wrote half of it. so it should be  `1770002.4756305092 - (926.6254331383334/2) = 1769539.1629139401`

Comment: sorry I got now. Probably GDAL read the up-left corner and Arcmap the center of the pixel

Comment: If that's the pixelsize. How can it be negative? `-926.6254331383334` is reported for the other way.

Comment: i don't understand why is negative

Comment: It's negative since it is a coefficient of an affine transform matrix, so it translates the opposite direction of the Y-direction. This is the same question as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/131273/1872